# How to call a function inside a class directly without using method in class

Tags: python

Name error : name 'addition' is not defined.

I tried calling a function inside a class directly without using method. How to call function directly inside a class.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def display(self):
        print("My name is :",self.name)
        print("My age is :",self.age)

    # calling a function inside a class directly without using method in class.
    addition(5,4)
        
def addition(a,b):
    print("Addition is :",a+b)
        
        
s = Student('Ashok',22)
s.display()
```

```
My age is : 22
Addition is : 9
```

Comment: With the `addition(5,4)` line indented as you currently have it, it gets executed during the definition of the class - before the `addition()` function has been defined.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined addition(a,b) function after class Student: so when class is getting executed and it comes to execution of addition(5, 4) its not aware of function addition because it not yet defined.

```
def addition(a, b):
    print("Addition is:", a + b)

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def display(self):
        print("My name is:", self.name)
        print("My age is:", self.age)
        addition(5, 4)

s = Student('Ashok', 22)
s.display()
```

This is right way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def display(self):
        print("My name is :",self.name)
        print("My age is :",self.age)

        # calling a function inside a class directly without using method in class.
        addition(5,4)
        
def addition(a,b):
    print("Addition is :",a+b)
        
        
s = Student('Ashok',22)
s.display()
```

The comments hard to explain, so, here is the why:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes

> When a class definition is entered, a new namespace is created, and
> used as the local scope — thus, all assignments to local variables go
> into this new namespace. In particular, function definitions bind the
> name of the new function here.

Valid attribute names are all the names that were in the class’s namespace when the class object was created. So, Python try add the `addition(5.4)` to its namespace, the function addition have not defined yet which question you reported:

```
NameError: name 'addition' is not defined
```

You can define the function `addition` before the class `Student`， not suggested here, the print is not you want.
Another way is move the `addition(5,4)` in `display(self)`. Python just add `display` not `display()` to `Student` namespace as the code I provide.
You can read the python docs, it's more detailed and specific, but I'm happy to help if you still have some doubt.

Comment: Would you please give an explanation?

Comment: Er, it's basis. Just make clear what happen while creating a class.
`When a class definition is entered, a new namespace is created, and used as the local scope — thus, all assignments to local variables go into this new namespace. In particular, function definitions bind the name of the new function here.` [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes)

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a python code, Python interpreter reads your code line by
line. So if you want to access variables, function, classes, etc. You must
define it before you use it.

Define the function before you use it. For example:

```py
def addition(a, b):
    print("Addition is: ", a + b)

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        # ...
        # ...
    # Other methods
    addition(5, 4)
```

**NOTE:** This is a bad practice to call a function directly inside of a class. This
works but disobeys the principles of
[Object Oriented Programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). So don't do that.

### BREAKTHROUGH

In this case, when Python interpreter reads through your code, it sees that a
function called `addition` is called which is not defined yet (at least not
defined before it is called). Thus Python throws an error.

To access this function, you must define it before. For example:

```py
def addition(a, b):
    print("Addition is :", a + b)

addition(5, 4)
```

It works but now you want the function to call **directly** inside of a class.
You do it like this:

```py
class Student:
    # Other methods
    def addition(a, b):
        print("Addition is: ", a + b)

    addition(5, 4)
```

But, judging the snippet that you have provided, you don't want to define the
function inside of the class, you want it to be **outside of the class**. Then
just put it outside of the class. But must define it before you define the
class. For example:

```py
def addition(a, b):
    print("Addition is: ", a + b)

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        # ...
        # ...
    # Other methods
    addition(5, 4)
```

But if you want to define the function **outside of the class and also after
definition of the class**. Then you don't have any choice but call the
function to do as inside of a method of the class. You can do as
[jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) said. This
will call the function when you call the `display()` method. For example:

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def display(self):
        print("My name is :",self.name)
        print("My age is :",self.age)
        addition(5,4)

def addition(a,b):
    print("Addition is :",a+b)


s = Student('Ashok',22)
s.display()
```

Comment: Why is it "bad practice to call a function directly inside a class"? It's effectively what you do any time you write a decorator like `property` or `staticmethod`